# "Recently he insured for" vs."He insured recently for"

Tags: adverbs

**Recently he insured for / He insured recently for** a mediclaim policy.

As per my understanding the adverb should be placed as near as possible to the verb it modifies, so I think the latter option is more apposite. Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't find *insure for a mediclaim policy* very idiomatic (*take out a mediclaim [insurance] policy* sounds more natural to me). So I'll switch it to something I find more "normal"...

> 1: Recently he applied for a loan.
>    2: He recently applied for a loan.
>    3: He applied recently for a loan.
>    4: He applied for a loan recently.

All four versions are perfectly acceptable grammatically speaking, but they're listed in what I would see as increasing order of frequency (#1 is the least common, #4 is probably *most* common). If it's possible to distinguish any difference in nuance of meaning, I would say the first two *may* place more emphasis on the fact that it was done recently, rather than emphasising the action itself.

That possible nuance is simply a consequence of *recently* not being in a position we'd normally expect. If we bother trying to figure out *why*, we'd probably end up thinking *"because **recently** is important here."*

Comment: My thought is that only #2 of your four choices will get much use.  I think #3 & 4 aren't particularly natural.  I don't have evidence (none of “recently he applied,he recently applied,he applied recently” show up in googlengrams) except that [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recently+we+applied%2Cwe+recently+applied%2Cwe+applied+recently&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *recently we applied,we recently applied,we applied recently* shows instances only of  “we recently applied”. BTW, I see “insure for a mediclaim policy” as wrong, not just off.

Comment: @jwpat: The problem is there are *very* subtle factors that might affect placement of a word like *recently*. From Google Books: [Recently I was in London](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Recently+I+was+in+london%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):9 hits, [I recently was in London](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+recently+was+in+London%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):1, [I was recently in London](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+was+recently+in+London%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):718. But they're dwarfed by...

Comment: [I was in London recently](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+was+in+London+recently%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) with 5490. There's no obvious reason why *being in London* should be any different to *applying for a loan*.

Comment: ...but I will accept that in the specific case of *he applied for a loan*, I did actually think most likely #2 would be more common than #3. I left them that way round because I wanted to lump #1 & #2 together as emphasising *recently* more. It's not an exact science anyway, particularly without more context.